# Проблема с PDO

Tags: pdo, php, классы, mysql

Здравствуйте, написал маленькую обёртку PDO

```
class DB extends PDO {

private $engine = 'mysql';
private $host = 'localhost'; // Адрес mysql сервера
private $database = 'qa';        // Название Базы Данных
private $user = 'qa';        // Пользователь 
private $pass = 'qa';        // Пароль
public function __construct() {
    $this->engine = 'mysql'; 
    $this->host = 'localhost';

    $dns = $this->engine.':dbname='.$this->database.";host=".$this->host; 
    parent::__construct( $dns, $this->user, $this->pass );

 }
}
```

Потом подключаю `$db = new DB();`
После подключения хочу вытащить кое-что из бд:

```
$sql = $db->query('SELECT site from site_config');
//Установка fetch mode
$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Появляется вот такие ошибки:

> Warning: PDO::query():
> SQLSTATE[00000]: No error: PDO
> constructor was not called in
> /home/www-data/www/test/core/data/config.php
> on line 8
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function
> setFetchMode() on a non-object in
> /home/www-data/www/test/core/data/config.php
> on line 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы была возможность напрямую пользоваться классом, так как делаете это вы, то нужно в конструкторе возвращать instance PDO класса.

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->db = $db;

return $db;
```

Comment: @zhenyab всё, щас заработало, не подскажите, как мне объявить подключение в другом классе, т.е есть независимый класс, в нём есть методы в которых выполняются sql запросы, в этом классе в конструкторе может как нибудь переопределить PDO

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "переопределить PDO"? Подключение к другой БД? Или интегрировать этот класс в другой?

Comment: @zhenyab вызвать класс с PDO в новом, ну всё, я в конструкторе в номом классе сделал так: 
public function __construct(){
  $db = new DB();
  $this->db = $db;
}

Comment: странная рекомендация...

Comment: Полагаю, это продолжение работы http://hashcode.ru/questions/235185/php-как-в-классе-определить-pdo .

Зачем расширять PDO? Дайте классу DB статический инстанс PDO, в нем же (классе) можете делать проверки, count-ы, fetch-и и т.п. .

Если вы решаете вышеприведенный вопрос, то расширение PDO вам никак не поможет